What SHA-1 certificate fingerprint am I supposed to use for API key for Google Maps?
I am making an Android application with React Native. The application uses Google Maps and I've generated API key that I use for geocoding. When I remove all restrictions for API key, everything works fine, but I want to use restrictions.

I've tried using SHA-1 certificate fingerprint I've got from Google (App signing), and I tried to use credentials I've got from Expo. I've followed the whole documentation but any fingerprint I set isn't authorized to use API key. I've also tried to provide a debug certificate fingerprint, but still didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Can you provide each steps you took?
